# Why is initial frame sticky on launch? How can I stop it?

Tags: init-file, frames

After a recent version change, my Emacs 24.5 is now making its initial frame (window) "sticky" on launch.  I am having to unstick it manually, which is a royal pain.  I tried using the Emacs variable `initial-frame-alist` to make it not sticky, but this does not seem to work.

Here is what `C-h v` says about the variable:

```
initial-frame-alist is a variable defined in `frame.el'.
Its value is ((sticky) (vertical-scroll-bars))
Original value was nil
```

Note that `(sticky)` means `(sticky . nil)`.

Some more diagnostic information:

1. When I launch my normal emacs with init file, the resulting window is sticky
2. When I launch using `emacs -q` (no init file), then run the init file (either with `M-x eval-buffer` or with `M-x load-file`), the resulting window is *not* sticky.
3. I am running `desktop-save-mode`.  When I launch a second emacs while the first is running, the initial frame opens with the initial settings, and it prompts me that the desktop file is already in use by another process—should I use it?  At that point the window is not sticky.  But after I respond `n` and the initialization process finishes, the window then becomes sticky.

I'd appreciate any help diagnosing the source of the stickiness and putting a stop to it.  My `.emacs` file is shown at http://pastebin.com/6tdc0dPM.  Please treat it gently; it's the result of over 30 years of accretion.

Comment: Have you looked into the last line of the init file?

Comment: @p_wiersig yes, that line `(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(sticky . nil))` was my attempt to turn the stick property off.  It seems to have no effect.  (But see my ETA above.)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `sticky` property was set in my saved desktop, and that executing `(desktop-save-mode 1)` was enough to turn it on.

I solved the problem by using `emacs -q` to edit the desktop save file to remove the `(sticky . t)` from a property list.